# Extracting ID and Relevant data from a csv dataset in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

Making a program for my Final Year Project.
Program takes the longitude and latitude coords from a .csv dataset and plots them on the map.
Issue I am having is there is multiple ID's and this totals 445,000+ points.

How would I refine it so the program can differentiate between the IDs?

```
 def create_image(self, color, width=2):
    # Creates an image that contains the Map and the GPS record
    # color = color the GPS line is
    # width = width of the GPS line
    data = pd.read_csv(self.data_path, header=0)
    # sep will separate the latitude from the longitude
    data.info()
    self.result_image = Image.open(self.map_path, 'r')
    img_points = []
    gps_data = tuple(zip(data['latitude'].values, data['longitude'].values))

    for d in gps_data:
        x1, y1 = self.scale_to_img(d, (self.result_image.size[0], self.result_image.size[1]))
        img_points.append((x1, y1))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(self.result_image)
    draw.line(img_points, fill=color, width=width)
```

I have also attached the [github project here](https://github.com/JagerScouser/Alex_Hulme_FYP) the program works but I am just trying to minimize how many users it plots at once.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a snippet from your data frame. Is the ID part of it?

Comment: Does this problem have anything to do with `tkinter`? I can't see any code related to `tkinter`

Comment: @TheLizzard sorry, yes the GUI is using TKinter and the main execute command is from the tkinter side.

Comment: @PonyTale as in from the .csv file?
As the ID is called iPhoneUID. I haven't implemented it yet as I am unsure how to tackle the issue. I will add the dataset to the GitHub

Comment: @JagerScouser Do you think that a person needs to know how to use `tkinter` to solve your problem? From what I can understand the problem can be solved with little to no knowledge about tkinter. If I am correct please remove the `tkinter` tag

Comment: @TheLizzard removed. Apologies.

Comment: @JagerScouser as far as I understand you have a dataset (the csv) with a lot of points described by long and lat coordinates. You don't want to plot all of these, but only the coordinates with a specified ID. Is the ID part of the dataset and does each point belong to an ID?

Comment: @PonyTale Oh! Yes it does. Every point is linked to an ID. I just have a lot of different IDs in one dataset and would like to allow the user to pick one ID's worth of points to plot? If that makes any sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check for a specific ID you could create a filter. For this dataframe

```
    long    lat     ID
0   10      5       test1
1   15      20      test2
```

you could do the following:

```
id_filt = df_data['ID'] == 'test1'
```

This can be used to filter out every entry from the dataframe that has the ID 'test1'

```
df_data[id_filt]


long    lat     ID
10      5       test1
```